# Get conferences when "All Categories" is clicked independently of the conference category

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code so that when a category is clicked it appears only the conferences that belongs to that clicked category.

And its working fine.

But I also have a link "All Categories", and I want that when this link is clicked get the last 8 conferences independently of the category.

But Im not understanding how that can be properly achieved. Do you know how? Is necessary to create another route for "All categories" and a specific method for that link? Or is possible to reuse the route method that are already working for when the user click in a specific category?

HTML:

```
<ul class="modal-list row">
    <li>
        <a name="category" id="">All Categories</a>
    </li>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <li>
            <img src="{{ $category->image }}"/>
            <a name="category" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

jQuery and AJax:

```
$("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    if($(this).closest(".modal-list").length) {
        $('#showCategories').html($(this).text()+' <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        $('.clicked_category').html($(this).text());
        $('#categoriesModal').modal('hide');
        $('#showCategories').parent('li').addClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    }


    var category_id = $(this).attr("id");

    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');



    $.ajax({

        url: '{{ route('category.conferences',null) }}/' + category_id,
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(result){
            $('#conferences').empty();
            var newConferences='';
            var placeholder = "{{route('conferences.show', ['id' => '1', 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";
            $.each(result, function(index, conference) {
                newConferences += '<div>\n' +
'                        <div>\n' +
'                            <div>\n' +
'                                <h5>'+conference.name+'</h5>\n' +
'                            </div>\n' +
'                          
'                    </div></div>';
            });
            $('#conferences').html(newConferences);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error.status)
        }

    });
});
```

Route:

```
Route::get('conferences/where/category/{id}',
'ConferenceController@WhereHasCategory')
 ->name('category.conferences');
```

Method to get the conferences:

```
 public function WhereHasCategory(Request $request)
    {
        $conferences = Category::find($request->id)->conferences;
        return response()->json($conferences);
    }
```

Conference model:

```
public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
```

And the pivot table structure:

```
Schema::create('category_conference', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('conference_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: make a descending limit query

Comment: Thanks, but is necessary to create another route and method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$conferences = Category::find($request->id)->conferences;
return response()->json($conferences);
```

You can make this query:

```
$query = Conference::query();

if($request->id){
    $query->whereHas('categories', function($q) use($request){
        $q->where('categories.id', $request->id);
    };
}else{ 
    $query->orderBy('id','desc')->take(8); 
}

$conferences = $query->get();


return response()->json($conferences);
```

There are other ways to do it like it is often the case in programming.

Also, you can simply `return $conferences`, it'll be converted to json if i'm not mistaking :)

Comment: Thanks, but what is necessary is have both queries. Because if the user click in a specific category it should appear the conferences that belong to that category. But if the user click in "All categories" instead of a specific category it should show the 8 conferences independently of the category.

Comment: I just edited my answer, i hope it should answer your comment

Comment: Thanks, but like that shows "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `conferences` where `category_id` = 1) " when a specific category is clicked.

Comment: It was obviously a placeholder but i assume that if each conference belongs to a category and a category has many conferences, you should have a column to link a conference to the category no ? You should use the name of this column instead of category_id. If you have any doubt, edit your question with the conference model ok ?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with that. There is a pivot table category_conference.

Comment: Perfect. Just to be sure you didn't make a mistake with your relationship, can a conference be linked to multiple categories in your application ?

Comment: Yes, a conference can have a maximum of 3 categories.

Comment: Thanks, now it appears "Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `conferences` where exists (select * from `categories` inner join `category_conference` on `categories`.`id` = `category_conference`.`category_id` where `conferences`.`id` = `category_conference`.`conference` and `id` = 1)) ". But with "category_id" instead of "id" the error dont appears. But when the user click in "All categories" link the 8 conferences dont appear.

Comment: replace id by categories.id (in the whereHas statement only), my bad sorry :p

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why when the user click in "All categories" link the 8 conferences dont appear?

Comment: Can you check if `$request->id` is indeed empty when the user click on "All categories" ?

Comment: When "All categories" is clicked it appears "message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…}
exception
:
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"
file
:
RouteCollection.php"
line
:
179
message
:
""
trace
:
[{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]".

Comment: Ok i see, there is no route without id. You must add a `?` after the id parameter in your route, so it looks like this: `conferences/where/category/{id?}` . This way, the route will be valid with or without an id.